# Show that $\sum_{1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}$ is differentiable everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I have recently been trying out some questions on series of functions.In one of the questions, I was given a series $$\sum_{1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}$$
and now I am supposed to show that the above series is differentiable at every real number and I need to find its derivative.

I was wondering when a series of the form $\sum_{1}^\infty f_n(x)$ said to be differentiable at x?..is it when each $f_n(x)$ is differentiable?.. and if that is so,then I assume that I am done with first half of the question.

In the second half,should I show that the given series is uniformly convergent by using the Weierstrass' M-Test and hence differentiate the series term by term?

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main theorem regarding differentiation of series of functions [is provided at this link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/differentiation-and-uniformly-convergent-series-of-functions).

Here $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx }{n^3}$ is such that $\sum f_n^\prime(x) = \sum \frac{ \cos nx }{n^2}$ is normally convergent, therefore uniformly convergent by Weierstrass M-test as $\sum 1/n^2$ converges. As the series is also convergent at $0$, the theorem states that the series of functions is differentiable and has for derivative $\sum \frac{ \cos nx }{n^2}$.

Comment: Where did that theorem state series is differentiable?

Comment: Last line $...f^\prime(x) = g(x)...$. Have also a look at the proof which is instructional and refers to [Differentiation and Uniformly Convergent Sequences of Functions](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/differentiation-and-uniformly-convergent-sequences-of-functi).

Comment: From there,we get that the uniform limit of the series is differentiable.

Comment: Sum of series is differentiable..so the series is differentiable..is it?

Comment: Sum of series is just what is called series.

Comment: Yes..okay..thanks

Answer (score 1):

For  functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R:$

Suppose (i)  $f_n(0)$ converges to a value $f(0)$   and  (ii) Each $f'_n$ is continuous and $f'_n$ converges  uniformly to $g$ on any bounded subset of $\Bbb R.$ Then $g$ is continuous and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(0)+\int_0^xf'_n(t)dt=f(0)+\int_0^x g(t)dt.$$ Define the above limit as $f(x).$ By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, since $g$ is continuous we have $$f'(x)=(d/dx)[\,f(0)+\int_0^x g(t)dt\,]=g(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f'_n(x).$$

Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n (\sin jx)/j^3.$ Then $f'_n$  converges uniformly on all of $\Bbb R,$ and obviously $f_n(0)$ converges.

Every continuous $h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is the uniform limit of a sequence $(h_n)_n$ of differentiable functions but $h$ may be non-differentiable at some (or every) point. The sequence $(h'_n(x))_n$ may fail to converge at some $x,$ or the sequence $(h'_n)_n$ may fail to converge uniformly on some interval of positive length.